# Why can't I choose in the table? I do the same as others

Tags: javafx-8

```
 @FXML
 private void onEditChange(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ModelTable, String> event) {
   ModelTable tbl = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
   tbl.setName(event.getNewValue());
 }
```

**I want to change the contents of the tableview after the selection.**

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Do you want to let the user edit the value in a cell of a `TableView` ?

Comment: Why get the selection model involved, if the event provides you with a `rowValue` property?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a Listener and it is placed in the initialize method
When you click on a row in the table you then call some method that executes the behavior you want. We have posted the code that when the table row is selected we navigate to a new screen. We name our screens blablaPane before we navigate we set a couple of static variables so the values can be used on the next screen.

```
    private void toChildView() throws IOException{
    stage = (Stage)parentTVPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    childTVPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("childtableview.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(childTVPane);// pane you are GOING TO
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("diary.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Diary Entries by Date Entered and Title"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();  
}

private void showTableDataDetails(ParentModel info) throws IOException{
    if (info != null) {
        info =  (ParentModel) ptable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        strMONTH = info.getPMonth();
        strYEAR = info.getPYear();
        toChildView();
    } 
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    try {
        ReadFromParent();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ParentTableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    ptable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends ParentModel>
        observable,ParentModel oldValue, ParentModel newValue) -> {
        try {
            showTableDataDetails((ParentModel) newValue); // When a row of the table is Selected call
            // Proper Construction                       // showTableDataDetails method
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ParentTableViewController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    });
}
```